# Reducing parameter list of a Factory

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

I have a scenario in which a Factory can create either a cheap or expensive bike.

```
  public class BikeFactory : IBikeFactory
{
    public T GetInstance<T>(Guid userId, string bikeName, string bikeDescription, decimal value, DateTime shippingDate) where T : EntityBase
    {
        if (typeof(EntityBase).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)) && typeof(T) == typeof(ExpensiveBike))
        {
            Information bikeInfo = new Information(bikeName,bikeDescription, value, shippingDate);
            return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), userId, newIfo);
        }

        else if (typeof(EntityBase).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)) && typeof(T) == typeof(CheapBike))
        {
            Information bikeInfo = new Information(bikeName,bikeDescription, value, shippingDate);
            return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), userId, newIfo);
        }

        else return null; //for now
    }
}
```

Bouth entities CheapBike and ExpensiveBike hold a ValueObject Information that describes them (holds basic information about them ). As you can see the parameter list is ugly, but it is there so the parameters are given to the Information consturctor

```
  Information(bikeName, bikeDescription, vlaue, shippingDate)
```

and the CheapBike and ExpensiveBike constructor (holds the ID of the owner of the bike)

```
  CheapBike(Guid owner, Information bikeInformation) // same for Expensive
```

I am looking for a way to reduce the number of parameters, so the factory method GetIstance() would look something like this :

```
    public T GetInstance<T>(Guid userId, Inforamtion bikeInfo) where T : EntityBase
```

**Question**:

1. Should I allow the client to construct the Information ValueObject via ValueObject factory and pass it to the Bikefactory ?

   ```
    VOfactory.GetInstance<Inforamtion>(infoDto.name, infoDto.description, infoDto.value, infoDto.shippingDate)
    Efactory.GetInstance<CheapBike>(userId, bikeInfo)
   ```
2. Or just allow the client to construct the Information ValueObject ?

   ```
    Information bikeinfo = new Information(infoDto.name, infoDto.description, infoDto.value, infoDto.shippingDate);
   ```
3. Is this even a valid approach ?

Comment: It is a valid approach if the value you get from it is worth all the complexity. Why the generic Factory in the first place ?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I allow the client to construct the Information ValueObject via ValueObject factory and pass it to the Bikefactory?

That's a lot of factories, I might try to simplify it by providing an overload. One that accepts both an `Information` object or all the parameters.

```
public T GetInstance<T>(Guid userId, Inforamtion bikeInfo) 
    where T : EntityBase

public T GetInstance<T>(Guid userId, 
                        string name, 
                        string description, 
                        decimal value, DateTime shippingDate) 
    where T : EntityBase
```

Then I would allow them to instantiate the `Information` object without the use of the factory. Really, the only benefit of the factory in the case of ValueObject is to instantiate the `Information` object, which isn't useful - that's what constructors are for.

> Or just allow the client to construct the Information ValueObject?

Yes, see above explanation.

> Is this even a valid approach?

Sure, as long as the factory is being used correctly and is beneficial to the consumer.

Example usage:

```
var bikeInfo = new Information 
{ 
    Name = infoDto.name, 
    Description = infoDto.description, 
    Value = infoDto.value, 
    ShippingDate = infoDto.shippingDate 
}
Efactory.GetInstance<CheapBike>(userId, bikeInfo);
```

Or

```
Efactory.GetInstance<CheapBike>(userId, 
                                infoDto.name,
                                infoDto.description, 
                                infoDto.value,
                                infoDto.shippingDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would just wrap up the parms into your dto object and let the user assign them on creation. With that said, I would look over your design again to see if the factory is really useful in this case. If both objects returned from the factory have the exact same params then why have multiple objects at all?

```
void Main()
{
    var bike = Factory.GetInstance<CheapBike>(() => new Information()
    {
        Name = "BMX",
        Description = "..."
    });

    //or
    var bike = Factory.GetInstance<CheapBike>(GetInfo);
}

private Information GetInfo()
{
     //do some logic to populate the info object to be passed
     //into the constructor during factory initialization
     return yourPopulatedInfoObject;
}

public static class Factory 
{
    public static T GetInstance<T>(Func<Information> func) where T : EntityBase
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), func());
    }
}
```

Comment: CheapBike and ExpensiveBike are different entities because they behave differently and have unique identifiers. Example : ExpensiveBike has other properties that are common to every ExpensiveBike like `SkeletonSymmetry`, which is set by a method `DefineSkeletonSymetry()`.That symmetry changes in accordance to owners preffered terrain.  `Owner.DefineSkeletonSymetry("desert")`, but bouth CheapBike and ExpensiveBike must have bikeInfo in order to be constructed, and latter on the Owner can adjust SkeletonSymmetry

Comment: @user2153675 the answer would remain the same then. If you provide a function with the return type of the object to be passed into the constructor of your objects then you allow the user of the factory to provide their own way of injecting those values. In my example I'm just passing in a simple function that returns the DTO object but you could pass in a method that does logic to determine those values dynamically and still lets the factory create the instance with the values needed.

Answer (score 0):

What problems are you trying to solve by applying the Factory pattern to your design here?

Here's two common motivations to use a Factory:

1. To relieve the client code from choosing a concrete implementation
2. To abstract away a complex creation process

As far as I can tell, the clients of your factory are passing the concrete type they need to the factory (`ExpensiveBike` or `CheapBike`) so that voids #1.

Additionnaly, your factory only delegates whatever was passed by the client code to the constructor of the concrete implementation chosen by the client. In other words, your factory doesn't abstract away any additional complexity so that voids #2.

Basically, you should probably not be using any factories at all here, unless I missed something. Calling constructors directly will actually reduce the complexity of your design.

> "I am looking for a way to reduce the number of parameters"

Long list of parameters is often a sign that some meaningful whole concepts have been missed, but we cannot identify these for you unless we know the business.

Just like in good OO practices, look for highly cohesive data members and try to come up with a meaningful unifying concept. The concept that you choose must add value to your design. If the concept is too abstract or arbitrary it may be better not to group the information until you figure it out.

A good way to identify those concepts is to analyze the commands and see what data changes together. For instance, perhaps it's common that the name and description of a bike gets changed together, so it may form a `BikeDescriptor` concept.

E.g.

```
var descriptor = new BikeDescriptor(name, description);
var value = new Money(299.0, Currency.CAD);
var bike = new CheapBike(id, descriptor, value, shippingDate);
```

Comment: I have refined my domain in accordance to your advice, helped a lot, but I have one more question that came up on code review by a colegue. Should the creation ( same as in your example) of bikes be done in app(service) layer or should that responsibility lay in a domain service. To me it seemd overdoing it to construct domain service that handles bike creation and call it by a interface in the app layer. Argument was that domain entities should be constructed in domain and not in app(service) layer.

Comment: @user2153675 Application service methods are the right place to translate non-domain concepts into domain concepts most of the time.

Comment: @user2153675 Did you forget your question?